# IstioOperator and sidecar autoinjection

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, istio-operator

How to enable sidecar injection using IstioOperator? This is my config and it is not enough for that.

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: control-plane-1-9-4
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  components:
    base:
      enabled: true
    pilot:
      enabled: true
  profile: default
  revision: 1-9-4
  values:
    global:
      proxy:
        autoInject: enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to `revision` parameter usage during installation `istioctl operator init --revision 1-9-4`

If `--revision` is used then NS should look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    istio.io/rev: 1-9-4
  name: default
```

Issue report: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/32746

Answer (score 2):

Auto injection is enabled by default.

```
$ kubectl get configmap istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system -o yaml | head -6
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |-
    # defaultTemplates defines the default template to use for pods that do not explicitly specify a template
    defaultTemplates: [sidecar]
    policy: enabled
```

You can disable this by setting the value to `disabled`.

```
  values:
    global:
      proxy:
        autoInject: disabled
```

Now the `istio-injection=enabled` label on the namespace will be ignored.
You have to manually set the sidecar annotation in the apps manifest:

```
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
```

More on the topic in the [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/mesh/injection-concepts/)

I guess what you are trying to do is to enable auto injection on any namespace by default. That's not possible.

Comment: For some reason, it is not working (NS annotation is set). I have installed Istio using IstioOpertator as described here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/gateways/#installation-with-operator Is it possible to see injection logs?

Comment: Try using this guide for setup. https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/ The one you linked is for upgrading.